# How to fix a triangle that works as a pointer that comes out from a button?

Tags: jquery, css

This is what I want to achieve [image]

I made the jquery function but the problem is that I'm not able to fix the triangle under the button. It moves around with resizing the windows. It is not a tooltip, this div needs to fit into the page below because we still need to show the contents that otherwise would be hidden by the new div.

```
<div class="uparrowdiv">
                        <p class="titlep">Here are the tasks that you can do on the Audience page:</p>
                        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p><p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.uparrowdiv{
widht: 100%;
height:100%; /*min height of DIV should be set to at least 2x the width of the arrow*/
background: #eaf0f5;
padding: 25px;
position:relative;
word-wrap:break-word;
display:none;
}

.uparrowdiv:after{ /*arrow added to uparrowdiv DIV*/
content:'';
display:block;
position:relative;
top:-20px; /*should be set to -border-width x 2 */
left:71%;
width:0;
height:0;
border-color: transparent transparent #eaf0f5 transparent; /*border color should be same as div div background color*/
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $("#helpbutton_toggle").click(function () {
        var position=$("#helpbutton_toggle").offset();
        $(".uparrowdiv").toggle(200);               
    });             
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want the caret coming out from the blue box or from the help button?

Comment: @Waxi I think he just wants to keep the arrow in a fixed position under the button, when he resizes the window it probably moves.

Comment: Are the button and the div both right-aligned as in your picture? If so, can't you set the position of the arrow using `right` instead of `left`, and use a fixed unit related to the button's width rather than using a percentage?

Comment: For a pure CSS solution, you need to render the triangle as `:after` element of the Help button (which should not be an `input`), not of the `.uparrowdiv`. Then you can fix its position to be relative to the Help button. Currently its position is relative to the `.uparrowdiv` (based on `width`). So if the width is varied, the `left` will change accordingly. But then you need to animate the opacity of the triangle independently and still in sync with the opacity of the `.uparrowdiv` (which is done using `.toggle(200)`). I think the CSS3 transition should work well in this case.

Comment: Also how the position of your Help button is changed on resizing the window??? If it's docked to the right (I think this is the case), then you can try setting `right` for the `.uparrowdiv:after` instead of `left`, but still you need to set it to some fixed value (other than a percentage based on the parent div's width). The final solution is using jQuery/script to update the position of the triangle `:after` based on the calculated position of the Help button.